# Check if function head has matching pattern?

Tags: elixir

Given that my function does pattern matching directly in the head, is there a way for me to check if a function has a matching pattern for a given input without calling it? Kinda like `match?` but for functions. I don't care about `when` and I'm only matching against atoms or atoms inside tuples.

e.g.

```
def init(:ok) do
  ...
end
```

and

```
check(&init/1, :ok)  # return true
check(&init/1, :other)  # return false
```

I'm modifying state in a GenServer, using a list of functions that handle some of the input, and ignore others. Each function takes a tuple, some state and either returns a modified state if the function head matches, or returns the state if it doesn't. I have a try/rescue wrapper function for this right now, which isn't that pretty. The inputs are variable length tuples, with the first element being an atom identifier.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Given a little more context, we might come up with a more straightforward solution to your problem.

Comment: @PatrickOscity updated. Feel free to ask if it's still unclear.

Comment: @FilipHaglund It's not possible to check if a function head matches without executing the function but I think there could be several ways of achieving the same goal with existing tools. Can you show more of your code? I'm having a hard time getting what you're trying to do :|

Comment: Considering my answer was downvoted I guess I'm missing the question you're asking too.  I'd think you'd want some sort of case statement--that's generally how I do pattern matching within a function. But I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I'm not trying to pattern match within a function, but check if `def init(:ok)` would raise a `FunctionClauseError` on some known input right at the function head. I want to know which of my functions could handle this input, without executing them.

Comment: The pattern matching mechanism is the same between function heads and case statements so I'm still puzzled why this is not an acceptable solution to you.  I mean if it would match in a case statement it will match in a function so you achieve the same effect. I'd guess you haven't really figured out what it is you need to do yet and I think you're really making things more complex than they need to be.

Comment: Catching the `FunctionClauseError` silences any internal such errors that I want to propagate up, and it does a lot of unnecessary work building stack traces that are thrown away a few instructions later, over and over again. It's not a pretty solution, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, it is impossible. [`Elixir.FunctionClauseError`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/50293b46f13a86328f0ffabdcbb8592e29ac24c6/lib/elixir/src/elixir_try.erl#L117) is simply a wrapper for underlying [erlang `function_clause` **runtime** error](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/functions.html).

The check is done on the fly, one might check for any particular clause, but there is no list of clauses prepared to check against. The good example would be a greedy cat, sitting in front of you; you might try to feed her with an apple, a carrot or even with a paperclip, but unless you have tried, one can’t say whether she will eat it or not.

On the other hand, one always has an option to query about [`Module.__info__ :functions`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Module.html#__info__/1). It responds with an arity, so one might detect and reject all `Elixir.UndefinedFunctionError`s.

But clause match is done in runtime, hence there is no way to receive a list of permitted clauses. Consider that clauses could be a cumbersome tangle of guards (`when`,) explicit params (`:ok`) and they even might overlap.

---

The question, as it stated:

```
check(&init/1, :ok)  # return true
check(&init/1, :other)  # return false
```

has a bruteforce solution, though. I wouldn’t recommend it, but it’s still available: implement `check` as *call the function and rescue from `Elixir.FunctionClauseError`*.

Please, also, don’t share I was the guy who had this suggested.

Comment: Your brute-force solution is the one I'm currently using, but I don't agree with it being impossible in the general case. I could write a macro that extracts the first argument to a function clause and use `match?` or a case against it. I'm just asking for a more idiomatic solution with less magic. There is no halting problem here.

Comment: “I could write a macro that extracts the first argument to a function clause”—only unless you have complex guards. This is a very limited and contrived example of what clause matching is and this implementation will fail on legit Elixir clauses. My point was “it is impossible in general, that’s why it is not achievable by standard Elixir functions.”

Comment: But I do not have such hard constraints.

Comment: I understand that you have a very specific use case. The language itself supports _general_ use cases. In general, the clause match _is not reversible_ and I have just explained why. Even more, this approach fully contradicts the paradigm of erlang/elixir: “fail fast” means your code should _fail_ when there is no match; that is the intended behavior. For some reason, you want to handle those in advance—ok, but why do expect the language would help?

Comment: I don't think a macro to extract the arguments of all `def` will have any problems with extracting guards -- it would just be a bit more complex to implement than extracting just the first argument. Why do you think it's "impossible in general"?

Comment: @Dogbert e. g. because the clause match appears to happen _in order of function declaration_, and AFAIK this information is not available on post-compilation stage.

Comment: Ah, I thought by macro OP meant the macro will get the whole AST as input. E.g. `extract do def init(:ok), ... def init(:error), ... end`. The macro will then return a `defined?` function and also return input AST as is. This shouldn't be too difficult that way but would require modifying the code in all the modules that need `defined?`.

Comment: @Dogbert that is not a generalized solution, IMHO. The generalized one would receive an arbitrary “parameter list” and return `true`/`false`.